# Share castle windsor container between projects asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, solr, castle-windsor

I have a asp.net mvc web project and I have initialised my windsor container in my global.asax application start. I need this container for my solrnet facility.

```
private static IWindsorContainer _container;
        private static IWindsorContainer Container {
            get{
                if (_container == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("The container in global application object is null");
                }
                return _container;
            } 
        }

    IWindsorContainer IContainerAccessor.Container
    {
        get {
            return Container;
        }
    }

protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        if  (_container == null)
        {
            _container = new WindsorContainer();
        }
    }
```

In my library Project I have defined a class IOC

```
using System.Web;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace Collette.Library
{
    public static class IOC
    {
        public static IWindsorContainer Container {
            get
            {
                IContainerAccessor containerAccessor = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance as IContainerAccessor;
                return containerAccessor.Container;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my scheduled tasks for rebuilding the solr indexes, i need to access the IOC.Container.Resolve to resolve my index and index mapper class. But I get the object not set to instance for container. The container is empty here. I searched a lot and realised that IOC.Container is empty because the HttpContext.Current is empty. How do i access the windsor container during scheduled tasks.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The Service Locator anti-pattern is generally a painful way to go. http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/ How are your scheduled tasks being run? What is the composition root for these tasks? It seems likely that you may need a different composition root than your MVC project. http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/

Comment: Using this castle windsor container for my solr project. Im using Solrnet. In order to add my cores and there indexmapper class I had a container installed. We were not using container before.  My asp.net mvc project is used along with sitecore cms system. We are currently using scheduled task and setting tasks using sitecore.  I dont know how to find the composition root for these scheduled tasks. Also I read the document you gave about the service locator anti pattern , but with solrnet and multicore requirement im only left with service locator pattern. Is there any other pattern I can use.